# play a sound with tampermonkey before user has interacted with the page

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

As the title says, i want to play some kind of notification sound with tampermonkey **BEFORE** the user (me!) has interacted with the page. Why? The sound will tell me there is something of interest on the page. The first thing that comes into mind is the following:

```
function playSound() {
    try {
        var player = document.createElement('audio');
        player.preload = 'auto';
        player.src = AUDIO; // base64 encoded audio
        player.play();
        console.log('playing sound: successful');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('playing sound: failed');
    }
}
```

But of course this attempt is blocked by the browser/chrome because...

- this runs in page context
- and there has been no interaction from the user with the page

Audio files and unmuted video files can't be played until the user has done something with the page. anyone know a way how to play a sound file with tampermonkey that does not run in page context?

### solution for windows

1. open regedit
2. navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoplayAllowlist` and create all non existant keys
3. create a text value named `1` and add your url where playback should be allowed. for a tampermonkey script this must be the site where your script runs. lets take google for example `https://www.google.com`
4. if your script runs on multiple URL, add further entries like `2`=`https://www.stackoverflow.com`, `3`=`https://en.wikipedia.org`
5. close chrome and start it again. should not be required (according to the linked document from the other question), but for me it only worked after restarting chrome.

Comment: Please consider adding your solution to the existing answer linked at top of this question. If it worked for you, it will be useful others. Upvotes and good karma await.

Comment: added my solution to the linked question